# Make a Variable Speed Rotation Driver to Influence Another Object

Tags: constraints, drivers

What I want to achieve starts pretty standard: the rotation of object A rotates object B. I use a driver. No prob.

Where I’m stuck is that I want certain portions of A’s rotation to rotate B faster and certain potions of A’s rotation to rotate B slower.

For instance:

- Rotate A 0-90deg = rotate B 2xA rotation speed
- Rotate A 91-180 deg = rotate B 1/2A rotation speed
- Rotate A 181 - 270 deg = rotate B 3/4A rotation speed
- Rotate A 271-360 deg = rotate B = A rotation speed

This has to be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a scripted expression.  For what you have, given input rotation "var", you might use something like,

```
(2 * min(max(var, 0),pi/2)) + (0.5 * min(max(var-(pi/2), 0),pi)) + (0.75 * min(max(var-pi, 0),0.75*pi)) + max(var - (0.75 * pi), 0)
```

Rotations in drivers are in radians, not degrees, hence all the "pi"s.  Be aware that if you're going to read rotations of >180 degrees, you're only ever going to get them from "single property" type variables, never from "transform channel" type variables.  max() is a python function that returns the greatest of its parameters; min() returns the least of its parameters.

An alternative is to edit the driver curve in a driver editor viewport.  You can add new points to the curve and adjust the controls and handles just as you would any other f-curve in Blender.  Adjusting the driver curve would be preferable if you wanted smooth transitions (but you can use vector handles there to make sharp transitions if you want.)

Comment: Works well after adding another parenthesis before pi in the first section. My problem is that   as object A continues to rotate 360+ degrees, the last term in the equation controls it. I need the whole thing to reset when object A gets to 360 degrees. What i want is that object A continually rotates and every time it gets to the 0-90degree portion of its reset rotation, object B always does the 0-90 degree rotation. Is this possible?

Comment: Then replace "var" with "var%(2*pi)" to get rotation, modulo 360 degrees.  Fixed parentheses, thanks.

Comment: Replace all the vars in your statement with var%(2*pi)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Probably best to enclose it in parentheses, (var%(2 * pi)), for order of operations.