# Driver based off rotation speed

Tags: rigging, drivers, audio

Hello I want to make a driver that's value increases and decreases based off of how fast an object is rotating. such as a for a tank turrets motor when the turret is rotating

Thank you For any Help

Comment: Does this answer help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301680/make-a-variable-speed-rotation-driver-to-influence-another-object

Comment: Hi, @JohnEason I think that one varies with extent, not  speed? If we're into velocities, I think we're into simulation.. maybe GN?

Comment: @RobinBetts Could be. There are other questions there showing how to use expressions as drivers but I just chose the first in the list.